# Can I use the SQLiteDB (in Android) from Apache Server?

Tags: android, apache, sqlite

I know that SQlite DB has not a server need unlike mySQL or the others.. We can read it directly from file. (Am I wrong?).. So is it possible to create a SQLiteDB on an apache server path and read-write it?  (My computer is working as an online apache server right now, I have a static ip. I want to use this DB in multiple devices running the same android project.)

Comment: better to use central database

Comment: But I have to store these data online, they must be accessible from all devices using this app.

Comment: yes. do agree refer to the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)but you do need a web-server for it.

Request mechanism
Android App ----> webserver ------> database (mysql)

Respond mechanism
Android App <---- webserver <------ database (mysql)

Android App will use [JSON](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html) or [other](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) to get the data and display it

Comment: I know I can do it but I didn't want to use mySQL, if I do, I have to create a new DB in mySQL.. Also the servers and the JSON.... I already have an SQLite, no way to do it?? :(

Comment: sqlite is a local storage of the android app.. its not a central storage where the data is being stored.

Comment: you can use SQL-Server & Asp if you want doesn't matter